# Function inside "DOMContentLoaded" event does not get triggered

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to create a chrome extension for youtube.com, where the injected script should load right after the page has finished loading. However, the script creates an element using an id which is available only once the page fully loads and the videos have loaded. Current method used:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const wrapper = document.getElementById(<id>);
  const btn = document.createElement('button');

  wrapper.appendChild(btn);
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const el = document.getElementById(<id>).children;
   
  });
});
```

Comment: What's with `<id>` and `<Text>`? Are they placeholders for this question, or do you actually have that in your code? Are you getting errors?

Comment: You are using DOMContentLoaded wrong. [DOMContentLoaded ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest.json file.
Add this line inside content_scripts
`"run_at": "document_end"`

example

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["contents/content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],
```

Remove DOMcontentLoaded eventlistener.

You got error because:
your event callback function set after "DOMContentLoaded" event triggered.

Comment: I think the default document_idle is more appropriate. [Content scripts Run time](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#run_time)

Answer (score -1):

Most likely because your code run too late, after DOMContentLoaded has already fired. if you're using jQuery you can do

```
$(document).ready(()=>{...})
```

and in [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/) you can do

```
{
    const cb = () => {...};
    if (document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") {
        cb();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cb);
    }
}
```